# AngularJs How to prevent <script> tag being input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, xss

I allow a user to enter text using the following:

```
<textarea ng-model="UserComment.text" rows="4" required maxlength="4000" />
```

Now this allows the user to enter

```
<script>alert('Hello world!');</script>
```

This will be saved to my db exactly as entered as the script tag (if not filtered) - which is extremely dangerous.
I know when I render that input using the following ng-bind

```
<div class="user-comment-text">{{UserComment.text}}</div>
```

it will be sanitized by default and the script tags will be HTML encoded with < and > rendered as  `&lt;` and `&gt;` so the script tags are not executed as script. But it is dangerous to save these tags in my DB so I want to filter the `<script>` tag (and any other dangerous input) from being input - **what is the best way of doing that**?

I hope there is a better solution than a regular expression (ng-pattern) as getting this right for multi-lingual is near impossible. My current thoughts are to sanitize on the server using a c# case-insensitive regular expression in my controller to strip out `<script>` tags - but there are other scripting concerns too - e.g. img onerror event and a href with javascript URLs. I'd like to tackle the script element first and worry about the others later. Thanks.

Comment: will it work `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize`

Comment: Thanks behzad for the edit - I'd have preferred you left the original. e.g In British English sanitise is the correct usage not sanitize as used in the USA. See https://grammarist.com/spelling/sanitise-sanitize/ .

Answer (score 1):

Try a regex.

```
var rgx = /<\/?script>/gi;
var snippet = "<script>alert('alert1')</script> stuff <script>alert('alert2')</script>";
var result = snippet.replace(rgx, '[script]');
```

is a very simple example. The expected output would be

`alert('alert1') stuff alert('alert2')`

Instead of removing the  completely, you can modify to [script][/script] so its not lost on you that someone was trying to malicious. You can also check for the < and >

As mentioned above, sanitise everything and if your database is SQL to use SqlParameters.

Comment: Thanks - that's similar to my thoughts of using a reg ex but using it on the client instead of server, and i like the idea of replacing with [script]. I'm hoping someone comes up with a pure angular solution as I can't believe everyone needs to use this type of reg expression  to keep script away from the server. Lets see what other suggestions come in. Thanks again.